# Can't get Magento 1 adminhtml layout file to load

Tags: layout, magento-1, adminhtml

I was working on a large module and I couldn't get an `adminhtml` layout XML file to load. So I created a new test module to isolate the issue and I still can't get the layout file to load.

I don't think my layout file is loading because if I turn on developer mode and mess up my `config.xml` or my `adminhtml.xml` then I get errors. But if I mess up the XML in my layout file then there are no errors.

Here's my config.xml:

```
#File: app/code/local/TestBlue/MeLayout/etc/config.xml

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <TestBlue_MeLayout>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </TestBlue_MeLayout>
    </modules>

    <admin>
        <routers>
            <testblue_melayout>
                <use>admin</use>
                <args>
                    <module>TestBlue_MeLayout</module>
                    <frontName>me-layout</frontName>
                </args>
            </testblue_melayout>
        </routers>
    </admin>

    <adminhtml>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <testblue_melayout>
                    <file>testblue_melayout.xml</file>
                </testblue_melayout>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </adminhtml>
</config>
```

Here's my adminhtml.xml:

```
#File: app/code/local/TestBlue/MeLayout/etc/adminhtml.xml

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <menu>
        <sales>
            <children>
                <testblue_melayout>
                    <title>Me Layout</title>
                    <sort_order>1000</sort_order>
                    <action>me-layout/adminhtml_index/index</action>
                </testblue_melayout>
            </children>
        </sales>
    </menu>
</config>
```

Here's my controller:

```
#File: app/code/local/TestBlue/MeLayout/controllers/Adminhtml/IndexController.php

<?php

class TestBlue_MeLayout_Adminhtml_IndexController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        $this->loadLayout();
        $this->renderLayout();
    }
}
```

And here's the layout file that I don't think loads:

```
#File: app/design/frontend/mytheme/default/layout/testblue_melayout.xml

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="1.0.0">
    <default>
        <reference name="before_body_end">
            <block type="core/template" template="file.phtml"/>
        </reference>
    </default>
</layout>
```

Everything here works properly except I don't think that layout file at the bottom of my `config.xml` loads. In other words, if I click the new admin menu item under sales then I properly hit that `indexAction()` in the controller. But of course that page is blank and I want to put content there by using a layout file so that I can specify a .phtml file for that route but again I don't think the layout file is loading.

The layout file code that I put above is a copy of another layout file in the same directory that is currently successfully loading for a different module on the frontend(ie. the public facing site).

So how can I troubleshoot why this layout file isn't loading?

All I really want to do is put some content on this new admin route page. If I can't figure out this layout file loading issue, then what are some other options for displaying content on the page? Can I assign HTML to the layout right inside `indexAction()`?